# Issue while building the docker on M1 macbook pro

Tags: python, linux, docker, tensorflow

I am using recent M1 chip model of Mac, my base is image of Docker is of CentOS on top of which I am going to run a Flask application. This application requires to have Tensorflow installed to run the model written inside.

Now as we know that M1 chip is based of ARM64, how do I add Tensorflow to this image is the challenge.

I tried to do multi-staging by applying the Tensorflow docker image on top of CentOS image by turning on the experimental feature of docker, but then comes out with error below for other installation which is required for the app

```
=> => extracting sha256:5d43e8c7056a20768e9c36d57ba56227f71df1563d630d424f512efd7b028805                                                                                                     0.3s
 => [linux/amd64 stage-1  1/34] FROM docker.io/tensorflow/tensorflow@sha256:0118f3db64ddadf5d16f4b8d85ffb14228e194c0211c690562fb5dfd16fc86c0                                                  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/tensorflow/tensorflow@sha256:0118f3db64ddadf5d16f4b8d85ffb14228e194c0211c690562fb5dfd16fc86c0                                                                        0.5s
 => [linux/arm/v5 stage-1  1/34] FROM docker.io/tensorflow/tensorflow@sha256:0118f3db64ddadf5d16f4b8d85ffb14228e194c0211c690562fb5dfd16fc86c0                                                 0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/tensorflow/tensorflow@sha256:0118f3db64ddadf5d16f4b8d85ffb14228e194c0211c690562fb5dfd16fc86c0                                                                        0.5s
 => ERROR [linux/arm/v5 stage-1  2/34] RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                       1.6s
 => CANCELED [linux/arm/v7 stage-1  2/34] RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                    2.2s
 => CANCELED [linux/amd64 stage-1  2/34] RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                     2.0s
------
 > [linux/arm/v5 stage-1  2/34] RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip:
#76 0.946 /bin/sh: Invalid ELF image for this architecture

Dockerfile:52
--------------------
  50 |     FROM tensorflow/tensorflow
  51 |     
  52 | >>> RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
```

I am not sure what is the best way to implement this, can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to be confused. If the Docker image is not an ARM image, the binaries inside it cannot be executed on an ARM processor.

Comment: Arm itself provides Docker images for Tensorflow. I haven't tested this but you could give it a try: https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/b/tools-software-ides-blog/posts/aarch64-docker-images-for-pytorch-and-tensorflow